# Php google analytics api how to fetch date and time for post that user visit

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-analytics

I am using google analytic v4 API in word press.

But I get only page views, unique page views, visitors, uri path.

When I write ga:date for fetching date and time. But I get an empty array in response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We need more details to help answer your question. What code do you have so far?

Comment: please post some code what you tried, otherwise your question may be flagged and be closed soon.